# PHPUnit Laravel not running next test case

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I created a feature test but the problem is it is only executing the first test and never executing the next test.

```php
namespace Tests\Feature\Api\Auth;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Tests\TestCase;

class AgentLoginTest extends TestCase
{
    use DatabaseTransactions;
    
    public function test_successful_with_email()
    {
        $response = $this->post(
            $this->route_api_agent('login/email'),
            ['email' => 'someemail@gmail.com'],
            $this->createHeaders()
        );

        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }

    public function test_failed_with_email_not_found()
    {
        $response = $this->post(
            $this->route_api_agent('login/email'),
            ['email' => '000somerandombullshitgo@gmail.com'],
            $this->createHeaders()
        );

        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
}
```

However, this is the result:

```
./vendor/bin/phpunit
PHP Warning:  Module "mbstring" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHPUnit 9.5.8 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

{"code":401,"success":true,"message":"You are not registered yet"}
```

In which that does include not executing the second function. I tested it by using `--debug` flag, and this is the result:

```
./vendor/bin/phpunit --debug
PHP Warning:  Module "mbstring" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHPUnit 9.5.8 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Test 'Tests\Feature\Api\Auth\AgentLoginTest::test_successful_with_email' started
{"code":401,"success":true,"message":"You are not registered yet"}
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Test execution stops on failure. Repair your first test for green light - next tests will be executed.

Comment: The response is returning 200 in the test case, in which assertion should be fine, and should execute the next test. I can assure you that.

Comment: Also, it happen when I am using POST method only, GET method is fine (able to execute the next test case)

Comment: It's returning 401, just READ console output you posted. BTW, post on successful must return 201 CREATED, not 200 OK

Comment: That is the custom JSON response I created, not an actual HTTP status code. The HTTP status code is 200 since I also call it manually using `response()` method in the controller.

Comment: I am curious how are you getting a JSON response when you are doing a test... you have a `dd` or similar out there, else it should never print a JSON response... it just should say that the test was either successful or failed...

Comment: @matiaslauriti Yes, i think that was the problem, it should not output any JSON right? And the test should just continue since I receive 200 http status code. I cant find any solution however.

Comment: I think you have a `dd` somewhere in your code, it is really strange... you have to check the controller, and middlewares...

Comment: I have checked that out, I assure you there is no dd or any kind of that in the code.

Comment: I have tried creating new project, with phpunit version 9.5.5 its working fine, another project (that I have been coded) that has the same version, its also working fine. Upgrading this project to the same version,  its not working fine. Downgrading the new project to the same version as this project, its working fine.